# Login using facebook, how to keep userid across all pages?

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook, session, authentication

I want to use Facebook's log in, and then I need to display some data related to the user, which is in my databases.

The problem is that I have several pages, and I don't want all pages to load the data using Ajax, rather I want them to be created by [JSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages) based on the user id from the first time the user logged in. The problem is how to set the user id parameter in the server side, and keep it safe?

JavaScript can't set the session, and it is very annoying and have poor performance to load the page and then wait for the id from the Facebook session just to send it to server and process it --> send data back. This is good behavior for the first time user logged in only.

I am using [Jaxcent](http://www.jaxcent.com/) as the framework for Ajax which is based on servlets. For some reason, I can't get to work with the session object there which only works with forms inputs. And when I tried to put a hidden filed in, it is not getting into the session, only if I type the value myself.

How do I solve this issue?

I thought about a table in the database which I could quote the session id, and userid from, but then again I have the session id in JSP but the userid in JavaScript, I can't find a way to combine them.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a page that you would pass the user id (when you get it from facebook) and that page would store a cookie on the client, with the necessary redirecting of course.

You might be able to do that with AJAX to get rid of the redirection.

Answer (score 0):

Just set a cookie from your JavaScript code, and read that on the server. Note that you should include the full signed request if you need definitive values, as opposed to the user being able to modify them.